# Why can't Moshe hit the water?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, water, hakaras-hatov

As a kid I learned that Moshe wasn't allowed to hit the water because it saved him when he was a child and he had to show hakaras hatov (similar answer for why he couldn't hit the sand that saved him by hiding the body of the mitzri he killed). But the water didn't save him, the little basket, the Egyptian lady who yanked him out or even the sister who watched him might have saved him, the water didn't do anything. If someone was in a car accident an survived unharmed they would say the seat belt saved them, not the road. How can we make sense of this ma'amar chazal?

Comment: It may be more helpful if you were more specific.

Comment: @SethJ more specific about what?

Comment: #irony.........

Comment: I always kind of understood that it was in particular the reeds (סוף) that he was thankful to because they hid the basket.

Comment: @DoubleAA then he should be able to hit the water, no?

Comment: @PM Two possibilities (that I am making up right now): the reeds weren't that big and are considered just part of the water, so it really is the form of the water that saved him (like the form of the sand); or, the reeds were all along the banks and Moshe/Aharon hit the river standing on the edge not from a boat in the middle.

Comment: Because it's a liquid and not a solid?

Comment: See [Rabbi Josh Waxman](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/458/josh-waxman)'s answer here: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2012/12/why-cant-moshe-hit-water.html

Answer (score 2):

There was no benefit from the road because if the road didn't exist then you would have been fine anyway because you wouldn't have been driving. In no way did the road save your life. However had the water not existed in Moshe's time then Yocheved wouldn't have been able to hide him, so the water saved him by giving him a hiding place.

Comment: Had the water not existed, the boys wouldn't have been killed by being thrown into it. If we judge it for this one positive event, why do we forget its role in infanticide?

Answer (score 2):

Had Yocheved put Moshe in still water, whether or not the reeds were there, he would have [eventually sunk](http://www.kon-tiki.no/E-Exp_Tigris.php) or been discovered by one of Paroh's men.  Instead, she put Moshe into a running river which took him downstream into Batyah's sight giving him hope (and giving Yocheved plausible deniability so that she could nurse him).  Thus, the running of the water saved him as much if not more than the reeds.

Comment: Why would he sink in still but not in running water? I don't understand.

Comment: @msh210 Reeds are buoyant but not infinitely so.  Eventually they take on water.  Before sealants were developed, reeds had a limited lifespan.  See http://www.kon-tiki.no/E-Exp_Tigris.php on a modern reed boat: "One of the main problems during the Ra and Ra II voyages was that water absorption made the reed boats float very low in the water, covering their decks in water in the last few weeks."

Comment: Yes... that's why I don't understand why he'd float in running water.

Comment: @msh210 because running water took him somewhere safe rather quickly - before the raft could sink.  In still water, he just would have sat in the pond ad infinitum.  It's a combination of the river, raft-making technology and the miracle of Batya's bath timing.

Comment: With G-d's help, I will explain to you why this explanation is not right. In Shemot 2:3, Yocheved places the basket בַּסּ֖וּף עַל־שְׂפַ֥ת הַיְאֹֽר, **among the reeds on the bank of the Nile**. In the next passuk (4), Basya comes down to bathe וַתֵּ֤רֶא אֶת־הַתֵּבָה֙ בְּת֣וֹךְ הַסּ֔וּף, **and she saw the basket among the reeds**. Then she sends her maidservants (who הֹֽלְכֹ֖ת עַל־יַ֣ד הַיְאֹ֑ר, **were walking on the bank of the Nile**.) The basket did no floating down the Nile _Prince of Egypt_ style. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this over Shabbos and came up with a possible answer. I checked on the web afterwards and found this post. None of the answers provide an explanation that adequately compares the role of the earth saving Moshe by swallowing up the Egyptian victims to the role of the water saving Moshe. It would seem that the water too provided an active salvation.

Here is my best guess: They likely put Moshe in the water at the end of town that they lived which was far from the palace and normally the current would have taken the basket to the shore long before reaching the palace region and he would have been found by a random Egyptian who would have likely killed him (figuring he was Jewish child). The water kept the basket in the middle of the body of water far from the shore the whole time so that even bas paroah had to miraculously (or figuratively) stretch out very far to take the basket.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in Sotah 12b, Pharaoh's astrologers saw that the Savior of Israel (Moshe) would meet his end through water.* That was why the decree was to throw the boys into the Nile. Once Moshe was placed in the basket which was then subsequently placed in the Nile's water, the astrologers saw that the Savior of Israel had been "thrown" in the water and the decree to kill all of the baby boys ended.

Shemos Rabbah 1:21 continues and says that they no longer looked for him.

So in reality the Nile did indeed save him. Had he been hidden anywhere else the astrologers would not have been tricked into thinking he'd met his end and the decree to kill all the Jewish baby boys would have continued.

---

*See Bamidbar 20:7-13 to understand why Moshe's "demise" came about through water (albeit in a different way than the Egyptian astrologers were thinking).

Comment: Best answer, IMHO! :-D

Answer (score -1):

I think this answers it (Rabbi Nissim Yagen):

> Gratitude is not because someone did something for you. But rather if
>   you benefited, that's the keyword. If you benefited from somebody, you
>   must have gratitude (from the book Netivei Ohr pg.165 by Rabbi Nissim
>   Yagen). Even if the person did not have good intentions. That's why it
>   says by Moshe that he was not allowed to hit the Nile river, to make
>   it into blood. He had to ask Aharon to do it. A river does not care.
>   It does not care whether he lived or died. But since Moshe benefited
>   from the river, so then he has to have gratitude and he can't strike
>   it. Likewise in the talmud it says "the well that you drank from, do
>   not throw rocks in it". Even though the well has no feelings and does
>   not care, nevertheless since you benefited from it, you must show
>   gratitude.

http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=333

Comment: bottom line : maybe he wasn't saved by it but Moshe BENEFITED from the water. that's why he must have gratitude

Comment: But the guy in the car accident benefited from the road; it's not like he fell through into the sewer system.

Comment: not the same, the water did benefit moshe, as it provided him with an avenue of escape from the egyptians searching for him. Yocheved could not hide him anymore from the Egyptian police.

Comment: How did the water help? Yocheved could just as easily have left him in the dessert or in a tree. What was unique about the water?

Comment: unfortunately I think these kinds of illogical ethical answers are all too pervasive in orthodox Judaism, for example Moshe being afraid of the "merit" of Og king of Bashan who selfishly informed Avraham that Lot had been captured in order to take Sarah for himself after Avraham perished in battle. Using this logic did not Moshe benefit from living in the house of Pharoah as a child? Should he not be allowed to cause Pharoah and his household any untoward harm? Did not Moshe breathe the air in Egypt? How was he able to to call down the plague of boils (Shemos 9:8) by throwing dust in the air?

Comment: How did the water help? it was the medium which saved him. yes, if a particular tree saved him, then could be he would need to show gratitude for that tree also

Comment: Did all water in existence help or was it just the molecules that were present at the time? If it is the latter yet Moshe generalizes to the former then the same would be true with trees or air etc.

Comment: the nile river not all the water in existence

Comment: Perhaps you could answer that the water brought Moshe to bas Pharoah, the one person who could and would keep an unknown baby.

Comment: right the nile was the main vehicle of his being saved @Orion