# Intelligent machines and their Halachic status

Tags: technology, science, contemporary-halacha, artificial-lifeform

Given the recent advances in machine learning, such as the OpenAI GPT-3 (e.g. chatbot), it is not unreasonable to expect that artificial general intelligence (AGI) will be achieved in the foreseeable future. This may mean that there will be machines that will be indistinguishable from humans (except for physical appearance, at least at first), in that they will appear to think, interact, and even have feelings, aspirations, and a unique personality just like a regular person. There might not be any way to tell them apart from humans, aside from examining their internals.

How might halacha approach the personhood status of such artifical intelligence machines? Is there any precedent or halachic basis to recognize their status as intelligent beings who are alive? This would have practical implications in many areas, such as whether it's permissible to turn them off or destroy them, rely on them as witnesses and count them for a minyan, ask them for halachic rulings, whether amira l'akum applies to them or not, and many others areas of halacha.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131013/if-an-ai-is-programmed-to-be-a-rabbi-learn-all-that-is-required-for-a-semikhah-o, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6008/psak-halacha-by-ai, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121089/holy-artificial-intelligence

Comment: I'd actually like to focus on the humanity aspect, and whether an AI externally indistinguishable from a human would have halachic protection from being turned off ('killed'). Because if not, all kinds of ethical issues may arise. You might meet someone and become friends with them, have shared experiences, laugh, travel and have fun together, learn with them as a chavrusa, and develop an emotional bond with them. But then you discover that it's totally halachically ok to just take an axe and smash their head to pieces, because inside they're made of artificial neurons and not cells.

Comment: Check out discussions about the Golem of Prague. Related.

Comment: Also this will be pertinent to the points you just raised in your comment (humanity aspect): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/why-cant-moshe-hit-the-water

Comment: The Golem is qualitatively different, since it perforce _is_ distinguishable from a human (it can not speak, for instance).

Comment: AGI has the opposite problem, it might be distinguishable in the opposite direction (super intelligence)

Comment: On the lighter side:  "JEW ON A CHIP, Fantasy & Science Fiction; Cornwall; Dec 1997; Robert Grossbach [advised by 3 rabbis]; 93::6 , pp 9-25.

Comment: I can understand the question from a scientific perspective, since science is not quite sure what consciousness is made of. But given that we believe we're animated by a soul, what would be the basis for assuming a machine simulating human behavior would have any special status?

Comment: @shmosel That's a good point and may indeed become the halachic argument against giving human status to AI. On the other hand, we don't necessarily truly know the nature of what a soul is and all of the rules and workings associated with it. So who's to say that once an AI attains human (or higher) intelligence, it doesn't also have (or get) a soul? If the observable nature of a soul is in how it expresses itself (speech, intelligence, emotion), then a being displaying all of those characteristics may be said to possess a type of soul too.

Comment: We also believe there are levels of souls, going up from inanimate matter to plants to animals to humans. Each of those beings displays more complex behavior and intelligence, because of the higher level of its soul. So when we have beings that are equal to humans in complexity, or surpass them, it can be reasonable to suppose they also have a high level of soul (perhaps in an emergent way, similar to how plants have a higher soul level than matter even though their chemical composition can be reduced to inanimate matter).

Comment: I would think it's the soul that produces sentience, not vice-versa. As far as the type of matter that can "capture" a soul, it's hard to believe it can be purely emergent. Would you say an image of a plant has a plant-like soul? What about a 3-D hologram that also smells like a plant? Where do you draw the line? [Does a prosthetic limb need burial?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16669/prosthetic-limbs-in-halacha)

Comment: AI at best creates an illusion of qualitative sentience. No AI technology we know of will have a "personal experience" of what "it's like" to think and speak. It will have no qualia. We have not the slightest clue about how to create that yet, not a single step as been made. The Knowledge Argument proposes that qualia are not based on any logical structure so are therefore impossible to make using materialism. The human element of your question is more likely to receive answers as the sentience element is too hypothetical (they just "acquire" a soul? Is there any source for this in Torah?).

Comment: @RabbiKaii The comments are too restrictive to discuss this, but in brief: 1. Soul, sentience, and qualia are distinct (though possibly overlapping) concepts and so one does not automatically imply the other 2. The knowledge argument has many responses (and actually its original author has retracted). The same can be said of the Chinese room argument 3. Even if we accept the knowledge argument and say that there is phenomenal experience which is not physical, that doesn't preclude AI from having those phenomenal experiences (especially in the epiphenomenalist view).

Comment: Thanks. Indeed there are many opinions in philosophy. The opinions I bring are the ones that support what I understand the Torah sources on the matter to be saying about the mind body problem. You are right, not for comments